# Unicode escape behavior in Java programs

Tags: java

A few days ago, i was asked about this program's output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // \u0022 is the Unicode escape for double quote (")
    System.out.println("a\u0022.length() + \u0022b".length());
}
```

My first thought was this program should print the `a\u0022.length() + \u0022b` length, which is `16` but surprisingly, it printed `2`. I know `\u0022` is the unicode for `"` but i thought this `"` going to be escaped and only represent one `"` literal, with no special meaning. And in reality, Java somehow parsed this string as following:

```
System.out.println("a".length() + "b".length());
```

I can't wrap my head around this weird behavior, Why Unicode escapes don't behave as normal escape sequences?

**Update** Apparently, this was one of brain teasers of the [Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032133678X) book written by Joshua Bloch and Neal Gafter. More specifically, the question was related to *Puzzle 14: Escape Rout*.

Comment: http://www.javajee.com/unicode-escapes-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why Unicode escapes doesn't behave as normal escape sequences?

Basically, they're processed at a different point in reading the input - in lexing rather than parsing, if I've got my terminology right. They're not escape sequences in character literals or string literals, they're escape sequences for the whole source file. Any character that's not part of a Unicode escape sequence can be replaced with the Unicode escape sequence. So you can write programs entirely in ASCII, which actually have variable, method and class names which are non-ASCII...

Fundamentally I believe this was a design mistake in Java, as it can cause some very weird effects (e.g. if you have the escape sequence for a line break within a `//` comment...) but it is what it is...

This is detailed in [section 3.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3):

> A compiler for the Java programming language ("Java compiler") first recognizes Unicode escapes in its input, translating the ASCII characters \u followed by four hexadecimal digits to the UTF-16 code unit (§3.1) for the indicated hexadecimal value, and passing all other characters unchanged. Representing supplementary characters requires two consecutive Unicode escapes. This translation step results in a sequence of Unicode input characters.
>
> ...
>
> The Java programming language specifies a standard way of transforming a program written in Unicode into ASCII that changes a program into a form that can be processed by ASCII-based tools. The transformation involves converting any Unicode escapes in the source text of the program to ASCII by adding an extra u - for example, \uxxxx becomes \uuxxxx - while simultaneously converting non-ASCII characters in the source text to Unicode escapes containing a single u each.
>
> This transformed version is equally acceptable to a Java compiler and represents the exact same program. The exact Unicode source can later be restored from this ASCII form by converting each escape sequence where multiple u's are present to a sequence of Unicode characters with one fewer u, while simultaneously converting each escape sequence with a single u to the corresponding single Unicode character.

Answer (score 8):

Before the compiler actually translates the source to bytecode, the lexical translation phase will turn the statement:

```
System.out.println("a\u0022.length() + \u0022b".length());
```

into:

```
System.out.println("a".length() + "b".length());
```

Hence the result is 2.

Also see [this section about lexical translation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2) from the Language Specification:

> A raw Unicode character stream is translated into a sequence of tokens, using the following three lexical translation steps, which are applied in turn:
>
> 1. A translation of Unicode escapes (§3.3) in the raw stream of Unicode characters to the corresponding Unicode character. A Unicode escape of the form \uxxxx, where xxxx is a hexadecimal value, represents the UTF-16 code unit whose encoding is xxxx. This translation step allows any program to be expressed using only ASCII characters.

Comment: Importantly, it's *long* before the byte code emission - it's before any of the rest of the parsing is done.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the info. Maybe I should have used the term lexer instead of parser :)

Comment: @AR.3 Thanks for your answer, both answers are great and i have the hardest time to pick one as accepted. Anyway, i'm gonna accept john's answer, thanks again. I wish i could accept both :)

Answer (score 0):

It is just funny that the following works (taken from the reference)

```
System.out.println("a\".length() + \"b".length());
```

but the following produces a compile error

```
System.out.println("a\\\u0022.length() + \\\u0022b".length());
```

On the second one, the compiler should reduce the `\` and the `"`, put them together as `\"`, but it tried it and it doesn't compile (the `"` still closes the string).