# How do unicode character escape sequences work in Scala and Java, when used in naming

Tags: java, scala, unicode, compilation

I have recently read that in Scala it is possible to use Unicode escape sequences for naming.

For instance:

```
val B\u0041\u0044 = 1
```

Allows for:

```
scala> BAD
res0: Int = 1
```

[Run Scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/ONBXNlW/0)

My hunch is that it functions somewhat similar to how C's `#define <entity> <new_entity>` works, it simply replaces the unicode escape sequence with the rendered character, which is why `BAD` works in the example above.

In Java the same is possible. So I wonder if it has more to do with Java, than it has with Scala.

In Java the following is possible:

```
double \u03C0 = Math.PI;
```

Which allows for:

```
System.out.println(π)
```

How does this actually work under the hood ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion comes from conflating two completely separate levels:

1. Unicode escape sequences are processed at the level of individual characters. Strictly speaking, it happens even before lexical analysis. That means that the Unicode escape sequences know nothing about "naming" or "names" - when they are expanded, there is no information about what is currently processed: a name (identifier), or a reserved keyword, or some completely different language construct.
2. Information about what "names" are becomes available much later, only after the lexical analysis, once the sequence of input characters is split into tokens.

All Scala does is simply replacing the escape sequences `\uXXXX` by the corresponding Unicode characters. For example ([run ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/iCbysqW/0)):

```
fo\u0072 (i <- 1 to 10) pri\u006Etln\u0028"hello, world\u0022)
```

is a perfectly valid Scala program that prints `hello, world` ten times. So you see that:

1. The `\u0072` is expanded to `r` in the middle of a keyword (`for` is a reserved keyword, not an identifier)
2. The `\u006E` is expanded in the middle of another identifier (`println`)
3. `\u0028` and `\u0022` are replaced by `(` and `"` respectively. These characters wouldn't even be valid parts of identifiers (unless enclosed in backticks).

It simply has nothing whatsoever to do with "names". It's all about individual characters, and it happens before there are any "names" or "string literals", or "comments", which is why [such puzzlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901247/unicode-escape-behavior-in-java-programs) occur when Unicode escape sequences are used inside of string literals or comments that are processed by the code-highlighter incorrectly.

---

All of this seems mostly unrelated to what's happening with the macros in the C preprocessor.
The macros created using `#define` must be given a name that is a proper identifier (i.e. consists of characters, numbers, underscores), and if the macros have parameters, then the preprocessor substitutes those verbatim by the actual arguments at the invocation site. Nothing of this is possible with the Unicode escape sequences. Also, the C-preprocessor will not tear apart tokens: for example, if you `#define u0072 r`, the preprocessor will not go and replace all `fou0072`-identifiers by the `for`-keyword. It works completely differently, and has entirely different purposes.

---

*Update: more gory details*

If you take a look into [Scanners.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/62efa84505c52b86300bd694fcbcb591f01bf721/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/Scanners.scala), you can see that there is a method [getUEscape](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/Scanners.scala#L1027), which processes the escape sequences, and pushes single characters into a buffer. The only place where this method is used is in another helper method [getLitChar](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/Scanners.scala#L984), so that all Unicode escape sequences are always transformed into characters, before those characters arrive in the "higher level" methods like [fetchToken](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/62efa84505c52b86300bd694fcbcb591f01bf721/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/parser/Scanners.scala#L517). This is what I meant when I said that the processing of Unicode escape sequences happens even before lexical analysis.

As Alexey Romanov has mentioned in the comments below, the escapes will soon be treated differently, and expanded in fewer contexts - the changes in [this](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/ee1dd63dc53143975d41ed8efec6cc2c8f54ccd9) or [this](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/62efa84505c52b86300bd694fcbcb591f01bf721#diff-0023b3bfa053fb16603156b785efa7ad) commit seem relevant.

Comment: Note: this is planned to change in 2.13.2 (and 2.13 spec already doesn't mention it) https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8282

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on at what stage the character goes from \uXXXX to the actual character. I understand it isn't actually related to naming, but just possible to use in naming, .. but actually just possible in general.

Comment: @CodeMonkey The method `getUEscape` seems to transform the `\uXXXX`s into characters - I've added a few links. But keep Alexey Romanov's comment in mind when reading the code - it seems that in the latest commits, the behavior of the escape sequences has already changed.

Comment: @CodeMonkey cool, thanks for the ScalaFiddle. I moved it around a tiny little bit.

Answer (score 1):

A Java program is made up of a string of Unicode characters.

The \uNNNN notation is supported as a way of representing a single character that cannot be entered on the particular input device you're using, for example if all you've got is an ASCII terminal, or a typical US PC keybpard.

A Java compiler converts its input stream into a standard Unicode form by first processing Unicode escapes.  See [the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2) for the gory details.