# Retrieving unicode character from db in spring

Tags: java, spring, unicode, unicode-escapes

I have a value stored in a db say "test\u03C9test"

my code is along the lines of

```
var value = <my query> // working fine
try {
     test("<root>" + value + "</root>");
     //test("<root>test\u03C9test</root>");
} catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
}
```

my 2 method calls to test appear to call with the exact same parameter however the first does not convert the \u03C9 into its unicode character
it seems like maybe spring is escaping the backslash?

but trying
.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\"); is not having the desired effect. Am I missing something?

Comment: Closing question as stumbled upon an apache library that solves it for me. For anyone else interested in the solution: 

import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
String unicodeString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(valueFromDb);

Comment: Something is wrong here.  You should not need StringEscapeUtils at all.  `"test\u03c9test"` is exactly the same as typing `"testωtest"` (assuming the compiler knows your file’s encoding, which is probably UTF-8).  The \unnnn notation is interpreted at compile time, not at runtime by any library.

Comment: It's good that you resolved this yourself, but you haven't given enough details in your question for others to help. It really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And @VGR is correct that [Unicode Escapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) are resolved during compilation rather than at runtime, so fixing your issue by using `StringEscapeUtils()` doesn't make sense to me either. Also see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35901308/2985643) for more information.